# Why are my application menus blank (right click on program in taskbar in Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10

[image: blank menu]

The strange thing is it doesn't start off like this, if I reboot it will be fine for a while before going blank again. I've been living with the problem for over six months and I just have no idea what could be causing it. Google has been surprisingly unhelpful, maybe because I don't know the official terminology for those menus.

Happy to poke around and try things, just let me know what info you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follows [the steps to restart windows explorer](http://www.wikihow.com/Restart-Windows-Explorer-Without-Rebooting-Computer) by starting the task manager, finding windows explorer in the process list tab, and then clicking on the restart button in the bottom corner, the problem can be fixed without rebooting the computer.

Why does it happen? Is there a permanent fix? I don't know - but the workaround is good enough for me. I hope this helps someone else baffled by this long-standing Windows bug.